# How to retrieve CGRect frame from UITabBarButton?

Tags: ios7, uipopovercontroller, uitabbaritem, cgrect

My goal is to display a UIPopover for each of my UITabBarbuttons when the app for launches as part of my tutorial...  I'm doing the following:

How do I extract the frame from `UIView *tabView = [[appDelegate tabBarMutableArray] objectAtIndex:1];` Which is the first UITabBarButton.

```
Array AppDelegate: <UITabBarButton: 0x145d06a70; frame = (254 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17802c160>>
```

Right now I'm manually entering the GCRect of 254,712,76,55.  I get 712 by subtracting 768 - 56, and the popover is in the perfect position.  But I'd rather do the calculations by retreving the values...  So how do I extract the `frame = (254 1; 76 55)` part of the results above?

```
frame = CGRectMake(254,712,76,55);
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

- (NSMutableArray *)tabBarMutableArray;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
#define debug 1

- (NSMutableArray *)tabBarMutableArray;
{
    if (debug==1) {
        NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

    UITabBarController *tabController           = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSMutableArray     *tabBarItemsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    UITabBar *tabBar = tabController.tabBar;

    for (UIView *view in tabBar.subviews)
    {
        [tabBarItemsMutableArray addObject:view.description];
    }

    return  tabBarItemsMutableArray;
}
```

viewcontroller.m

```
-(void)showHomeTabBarPopOver
{
    if (debug==1) {
        NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CGRect frame    = CGRectZero;

    NSLog(@"%@", [appDelegate tabBarMutableArray]);

    NSLog(@"Array AppDelegate: %@", [[appDelegate tabBarMutableArray] objectAtIndex:1]);


    UIView *tabView = [[appDelegate tabBarMutableArray] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"tabView %@", [tabView valueForKey:@"frame"]);

    //    frame           = tabView.frame;
    NSLog(@"frame %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(self.view.frame));

    frame = CGRectMake(254,712,76,55); //254,712,76,55

    [_getStartedPopover presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```

Results

```
2014-02-07 14:35:47.940 mCC HD[1964:60b] (
    "<_UITabBarBackgroundView: 0x145d0cb30; frame = (0 0; 1024 56); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17802db00>>",
    "<UITabBarButton: 0x145d06a70; frame = (254 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17802c160>>",
    "<UITabBarButton: 0x145e2e360; frame = (364 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17003c2e0>>",
    "<UITabBarButton: 0x145d0a060; frame = (474 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17802c6a0>>",
    "<UITabBarButton: 0x145d0a640; frame = (584 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17802ca20>>",
    "<UITabBarButton: 0x145d0ae60; frame = (694 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17802cda0>>",
    "<UIImageView: 0x145d0edd0; frame = (0 -0.5; 1024 0.5); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17802f0a0>>"
)
2014-02-07 14:35:47.940 mCC HD[1964:60b] Running AppDelegate 'tabBarMutableArray'
2014-02-07 14:35:47.941 mCC HD[1964:60b] Array AppDelegate: <UITabBarButton: 0x145d06a70; frame = (254 1; 76 55); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17802c160>>
2014-02-07 14:35:47.943 mCC HD[1964:60b] frame {
    Height = 768;
    Width = 1024;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
```

Thanks in advance...

-PaulS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

*(Sorry, in my first answer I did not look at how the `tabBarMutableArray` is created.)*

---

In your AppDelegate the `tabBarItemsMutableArray` (which is the return value of your `-tabBarMutableArray` method) is created like this:

> ```
> for (UIView *view in tabBar.subviews)
> {
>     [tabBarItemsMutableArray addObject:view.description];
> }
> ```

Hence there are no `UIView` objects contained in that array but `NSString` objects (the descriptions of all the subviews). That is why the following line in your viewcontroller.m is incorrect and won't work as desired:

```
    UIView *tabView = [[appDelegate tabBarMutableArray] objectAtIndex:1];
```

The right hand side of that line is a `NSString`, the left hand side is a `UIView`.

---

You can fix this problem adding the lines

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];        
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabController.tabBar;
UIView *tabView = [tabBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
CGRect frame = tabView.frame
```

to your `-showHomeTabBarPopOver` method. (Though there are neater methods depending on what you want to do...)

---

If you need the frames for all tab bar items and not only this particular one "at index: 1" I suggest you create a property in your AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tabBarViews;
```

and implement its getter method in your AppDelegate.m:

```
- (NSArray *)tabBarViews {
    UITabBarController *tabController  = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabController.tabBar;

    return tabBar.subviews;
}
```

Then you can access your tab bar views more easily from within your viewcontroller.m including their frames:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

UIView *tabView0 = [appDelegate.tabBarViews objectAtIndex:0];
CGRect frame0 = tabView0.frame;

UIView *tabView1 = [appDelegate.tabBarViews objectAtIndex:1];
CGRect frame1 = tabView1.frame;
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation.  It's appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. :)